Closest edge to a rectangle in a plane of rectangles
I have a 2D plane (with discrete points) that contains arbitrary-sized rectangles and all rectangles are axis aligned. I have their coordinates (upper-left) and sizes (length and breadth).
Suppose I pick a rectangle in this plane and I want to find the closest edge to this rectangle (which also intersects with at least one of the projections of the adjacent side of the rectangle). Here is an example:
https://i.sstatic.net/bZbg4uDU.jpg (Link because of insufficient reputation)
My first solution was to check each side of each rectangle one by one and calculate its distance to each side of the given rectangle. But this seems very computationally expensive (especially considering this in a graphical context i.e. every frame of input)
Second was to check if this rectangle is colliding with another (with AABB) if not then by the relative position of their top-left coordinate I can determine which will be the closest edge for this pair.
Can someone propose a better solution to this?
Note 1: You can assume no other rectangles can intersect (with any other) apart from the given rectangle.

What do you mean by an "edge"?  What do you mean by "which also intersects...."?  Please read about the difference between "which" vs "that", and [edit] your post to clarify.  I suggest you break down that statement into multiple sentences, and use mathematical variables to refer to the objects it is talking about, to make it clearer what you are saying.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sweep_line_algorithm, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Persistent_data_structure
